# Need to Write a function which will find the depth of a nested dictionary. The function should able to handle python Object in addition to dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, oop, recursion, nested

**Sample Input:**

```
class Person(object):
    def __init__(self, first_name, last_name, father):
        self.first_name = first_name
        self.last_name = last_name
        self.father = father

person_a = Person(“User”, “1”, none)
person_b = Person(“User”, “2”, person_a)


a = {
    “key1”: 1,
    ”key2”: {
        “key3”: 1,
        “key4”: {
            “key5”: 4,
            “user”: person_b,
        }
     },
}
```

**Sample Output:**

```
key1 1
key2 1
key3 2
key4 2
key5 3
user: 3
first_name: 4
last_name: 4
father: 4
first_name: 5
last_name: 5
father: 5
```

How do I solve this which can handle objects? I can do this if it's only a nested dictionary. But a function should be create which can handle objects.

Comment: Please see my edited answer below for the full printed output

Answer (score -1):

You can use a recursive generator function:

```
def get_depth(d, c = 1):
   if not isinstance(d, dict):
      yield from [(a, c) for a in getattr(d, '__dict__', [])]
      yield from ([] if (n:=getattr(d, 'father', None)) is None else get_depth(n, c+1))
   else:
      for a, b in d.items():
         yield (a, c)
         yield from get_depth(b, c+1)
```

---

```
class Person(object):
   def __init__(self, first_name, last_name, father):
      self.first_name = first_name
      self.last_name = last_name
      self.father = father

person_a = Person('User', '1', None)
person_b = Person('User', '2', person_a)


a = {'key1': 1, 'key2': {'key3': 1, 'key4': {'key5': 4, 'user': person_b,}},}
print(list(get_depth(a)))
```

Output:

```
[('key1', 1), ('key2', 1), ('key3', 2), ('key4', 2), ('key5', 3), ('user', 3), ('first_name', 4), ('last_name', 4), ('father', 4), ('first_name', 5), ('last_name', 5), ('father', 5)]
```

Pretty-printed result:

```
for j, k in get_depth(a):
   print(f'{j}: {k}')
```

Output:

```
key1: 1
key2: 1
key3: 2
key4: 2
key5: 3
user: 3
first_name: 4
last_name: 4
father: 4
first_name: 5
last_name: 5
father: 5
```